# Representation of Column major order vs Row major order

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, row-major-order, column-major-order

Consider a 2D array "Array" that contains values : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. My major issue with the understanding of both orders is that if Row Major Order is to be represented as Array[i,j] (while i is row and j is column),

```
    [i0,j0][i0,j1][i0,j2]
    [i1,j0][i1,j1][i1,j2]
    [i2,j0][i2,j1][i2,j2]
```

So that if you are asked with a question such as "find the address of element Array[1,2] in Array[2][2]", you'd know that the number of rows come before the number of columns and it would be easy to put them in the formula:

```
    Base(Address) + w(dataSize){N(i - Row_lowerBound)+(j - Col_lowerBound)}
    While 'N' is the number of columns
```

does it mean that the column order can be represented as Array[j,i] which would mean that the Column number appears earlier than the row number. So there is no way of knowing where the i,j,Row_lowerbound and Col_lowerbound values of Array[j][i] (e.g Array[3][4]) are to be put in the formula.

for e.g if the question appears as: "Find the address of Array[1][2] in the array Array[3][4]" How would you know if 3 is the number of colmns or 4? How would you know whether the 'i' is 3 or 4?

Comment: "How would you know if 3 is the number of columns or 4?" is not important to answer to  "Find the address of Array[1][2] in the array Array[3][4]".  The answer is independent of which dimension is called "column".  Or are you asking something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know. There is no relation between how the computer represents the data and how you interpret it. Since you are "*free*" to interpret it the way you like, then it's your responsability to know which index is for rows and which one for columns.

Usually you can, write the specification in comments in the code itself or write documentation for functions using the structure. Also, you could write functions to access the array that enforce the order of indexes. But then, it's still not immediately unambiguous but has the benefit that you can check for out of bound access.

Comment: yes but what about a written question in which you are supposed to calculate the address of the matrix. If the question states to calculate it with the Column major Order formula, does the column number for array[3][4] be 3 or 4? because if it were a Row major order, it would definitely be 4.

Comment: @Zextro That depends? which one you want it to be? And that's the whole point of my answer. The interpretation is yours, and there is nothing predefined in this.